# Python / Nuke - Module DLL load failed in Nuke Enviroment

Tags: python, dll, module, nuke

I'm trying to load the win32com module in Python to use within Nuke. It does work fine when using the Python 2.7.16 enviroment on my machine but when I use the Python enviroment of Nuke it failes to load the DLL.

[Comparison of the two enviroments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3VqW.png)

This is the Python version of my local enviroment:

2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

This is the version that nuke uses

2.7.16 (v2.7.16-dirty:413a49145e, Aug  6 2019, 14:37:13) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)]

I'm not sure what this "-dirty" means. Might that be a reason why it's not working? Do I need a different version of the win32com module?

Comment: hmmm that is weird - i know that they build their own python interpreter, so maybe there's a problem with the version they're using. what are you attempting to do with win32com? is there maybe another module that would be more compatible?

Comment: @tk421storm 
I want to copy files but not with Python directly but with windows. So you get the Progress bar of windows and also the option to select if you want to overwrite previous files or not.
So basically Python only initializes the Copy process and Windows runs it.

Comment: It does work in Nuke 13 with Python 3.

Comment: I tried all of the Compatible versions of pywin32 (222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228) with the same result.